App_location on deployment of a static webapp
for the first time I am trying to deploy a site on azure as a static web app, for the code I am using a private repository on github.
The website is done using astrowind (https://github.com/onwidget/astrowind)
Locally everything works, giving the command npm run build creates a folder called dist inside which are all the files including index.html
The problem I am having is with the github actions, although the logs show that the dist folder is created, the azure action can never find it.
I have tried committing that folder as well, at which point the site is correctly published, but in this way I would have to run npm run build locally each time before committing.
Of course I could do it that way but then I wouldn't understand what the problem is ;D
Here is the azure .yml file:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "dist" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "." # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          action: "close"

Although I put dist as the value of app_location, it does not work
Any advice?

Update the App_location: '/' and output_location: 'dist' in the workflow. I'm able to deploy your project to Azure Static Web app. Image1, Image2.

Thanks @PravallikaKV it works!! <3

Update App_location: '/' and output_location: 'dist' in the GitHub workflow(.yml file).
I have deployed your project to Azure Static Web App from a Private repository on GitHub.
GitHub Workflow:
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GRAY_PEBBLE_05B26DA0F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_GRAY_PEBBLE_05B26DA0F }}
          action: "close"

Deployment Status in GitHub:

Portal:

Output:

